# Getting Xrefs to Windows Library Functions in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, ollydbg, malware, ida-plugin, iat

Ok so let's say that a program obfuscated its IAT and i can't see it in IDA Pro. In OllyDbg there is a plugin where you press `Ctrl+G` you can search for a library function and set a breakpoint even though that function is not listed in the IAT. My question is how can i do this in IDA Pro?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During debugging, you can use names in format "DllName_export" (e.g.  `kernel32_CreateFileA`) to jump to functions exported by the loaded DLLs, or you can use such names in "symbolic breakpoints" so they're automatically added when DLL gets loaded.

Also: double-click a DLL in the Modules list to see its exports and jump to/set breakpoints on them.

Comment: taking a look at the module list answered my question :)